# Equal line height with varying border width (border-box)

Tags: css

In this simplified example I have 4 circles, each with varying border-width and I am trying to maintain equal line height in each to keep them horizontally aligned.

However the border width seems to effect the line height (despite being technically outside the box?)

Is there anyway to solve this without manually adjusting each line-height?

```
width: 50px;
height: 50px;
border-radius: 50px;
border: 1px solid #1daeec;
line-height: 50px;
```

[image]

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/vcJ3G/

Comment: nice question, I think we should use jquery to do, because even putting as% of value, we always have an offset, would be able to evade the border and I see that the jQuery to do that http://jsfiddle.net/vcJ3G/1/ or add class for to vary line-height

Comment: When you set `box-sizing: border-box` the border is no longer technically outside the box. It is then included inside the width defined for the box. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing

Comment: This all can be avoided if `box-shadow` is used instead :D

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/techsin/vcJ3G/16/embedded/result/ check out the one at left

Comment: @GordonTucker good point! That explains it, had to use border-box to keep them all the same height.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can remove the line-height, use `display:table-cell` instead, and add `vertical-align:middle;` to your stat class.

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/vcJ3G/2/)**

```
.stat {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    border: 1px solid #1daeec;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 10px;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #1daeec;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

Comment: Nice thank you, I tend to avoid table-cell because of IE7 but I can choose to ignore that for this project.

Answer (score 1):

Your css works fine all you have to do is remove some from top section

```
* {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;

}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/techsin/vcJ3G/15/

Comment: I didn't mention that I had to keep the same height on all circles hence the use of the border-box. You are correct without that explaination though so thank you.

Answer (score -1):

Came across this and thought myself how is it possible to do it without using table-cell, my solution probably not the best, but I just decide to share it anyway. 
http://codepen.io/svdovichenko/pen/rObzqM?editors=110

adding `<span>1</span>` (can use class inside spam didn't use for this example)

```
.stat{
    position: relative;
}
```

and

```
span {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-right: -50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```